# How to make the column of one file as heading of other file's column with pandas in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 3 xlsx files named as data, vector and heading.

1. Data contains 5x5 entries ,[this is *data* dataframe looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g29zG.png)
2. vector contains 5x1 entries ,[this is *vector* dataframe looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wTu0.png)
3. heading contains 5x1 entries ,[this is *heading* dataframe looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE8RP.png)

I had taken each column from data file and find its correlation with vector

```
for i,j in data.iteritems():
col=j
coef, p = spearmanr(col, vector)
alpha = 0.05
if p < alpha:
    print('\n\nSpearmans correlation coefficient: %.3f' % coef)
    print(f' column {[i]} method are correlated (reject H0) p=%.3f' % p)
```

which gives me the output as

> Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000.  column[0] method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000
>
> Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000.  column[2] method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000
>
> Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000.  column[3] method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000

I want to point the particular column of heading so that my desired output will be

> Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000. Red method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000
>
> Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000. Green method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000
>
> Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000. Blue method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000

Any reference or resource will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your `heading` variable while printing. So, instead of using `column {[i]}`, you need to use `{heading.loc[i,0]}`.

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

data = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 5, 10, 76],
                     [20, 6, 10, 100, 87],
                     [40, 30, 15, 1000, 46],
                     [60, 9, 20, 10000, 43],
                     [80, 12, 25, 100000, 98]])

vector = pd.DataFrame([[60], [80], [100], [120], [140]])
heading = pd.DataFrame([['red'], ['orange'], ['green'], ['blue'], ['yellow']])

for i,j in data.iteritems():
    col=j
    coef, p = spearmanr(col, vector)
    alpha = 0.05
    if p < alpha:
        print('\n\nSpearmans correlation coefficient: %.3f' % coef)
        print(f' {heading.loc[i,0]} method are correlated (reject H0) p=%.3f' % p)
```

where it produces the following output:

```
Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000
 red method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000


Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000
 green method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000


Spearmans correlation coefficient: 1.000
 blue method are correlated (reject H0) p=0.000
```